# Android Inflate View exception

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have created an app which use to work fine till I moved it to gradle.

I had a custom Textview and I used as below in XML

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_message"
            style="@style/Container">


            <co.customview.FontTextView
                android:id= "@+id/header_message"
                style= "@style/TextAppearance.SubTitle"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/gap_small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Styles defined are as below

```
 <style name="Container">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
 </style>


<style name="TextAppearance.SubTitle" >
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

Now for each custom view we started getting below error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity android.view.InflateException: 
Binary XML file line #57: Binary XML file line #57: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
                                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
                                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
                                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
                                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Binary XML file line #57: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
                                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                                                            at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:19784)
```

Comment: Did you try to remove `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` from fontview

Comment: Please read the error "You must supply a layout_height attribute." ..In your case "co.customview.FontTextView" doesn't have  layout_height attribute.

Comment: @sunilsunny He is using custom style.

Comment: Then comment the custom style and check if setting  layout_height solve the problem.If yes then you know where the problem is ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<co.customview.FontTextView
                    android:id= "@+id/header_message"
                    style= "@style/TextAppearance.SubTitle"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/gap_small"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

to

```
<co.customview.FontTextView
                        android:id= "@+id/header_message"
                        style= "@style/TextAppearance.SubTitle"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/gap_small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

You have'nt specified **layout_height** attribute.

Comment: Yes doing so solves my issue. BUt there are tons of files like this. I need to find the root cause why its happening like this

Comment: For every view you add need to specify width and height.

Comment: @MRX : You can accept my answer if my solution works. Thank you

Comment: This is a work around which I tried before posting the question . I just need a generic solution so that I don't have to do it to all my files